# pg_commit_ts growing in postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a customer who is trying to set up bidirectional replication with logical replication publication/subcription model across two instances with the help of last_update_wins and reported that with little to no activity he is running out of space. He only have a 5 GB disk as of now with his POC out of which ~2 GB is occupied by wal files (no big fluctuation with the usage) however from the Host console I see that there pg_commit_ts folder keeps growing and is currently @1.7 GB

```
2.4G    pg_wal
1.7G    pg_commit_ts
96M     db/base
44M     /pg_xact
```

From postgres documentation I see that this is Subdirectory containing transaction commit timestamp data. I then noticed that he also have enabled "track_commit_timestamp" which collects commit time of transactions.

I'm trying to figure out 1. Is there any way to control retention on pg_commit_ts   2. Is this normal to have huge "pg_commit_ts" with the parameter enabled or does this have to do with their use case.

Please advise.

Comment: Hard to say what is going on here, since pg_commit_ts does not exist in version 9.3.

Comment: came to find out, that unless the XIDs are cleared by vacuum / autovacuum pg_commit_ts would not be cleared.

Answer (score 2):

came to find out, that unless the XIDs are cleared by vacuum / autovacuum pg_commit_ts would not be cleared. So basically this instance needs attention on tuning autovacuum parameters to run autovacuum efficiently